# how to get rid of "used but not defined" warning when compiling functions defined in asm on mips?

Tags: gcc, mips, gcc-warning

Compiling this program for mips with gcc (i.e., `mips-linux-gnu-gcc`):

```
__asm__
(
  "f_asm:\n"
  "jr $ra\n"
  "nop\n"
);

static void f(void) __asm__("f_asm");

int main(void)
{
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

Yields this warning:

```
a.c:8:13: warning: 'f' used but never defined
 static void f(void) __asm__("f_asm");
             ^
```

I'd like to get rid of this warning without making the symbol global. However, I haven't been able to find a `-Wno-` option that makes it go away. Any ideas?

(Note that changing `f_asm` to `f` does not improve the situation).